# How to find the publish path in Websphere Application Server v8.0

Tags: java, websphere, publish, ibm-rad

In my local workspace, i separated my application into several web applications, which are wrapped with EAR, then publish it to Websphere Application Server v8.0, in previous version of WAS, i can find the place that my WAS published, but i can't find it for WAS v8.0, anybody have idea.

BTW, i am using IBM Rational Application Developer v8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Execute a *simple* JSP file in your Web Application with the following lines:

```
<h1>Real Path for this Context</h1>
<hr>
<h3>${pageContext.servletContext.getRealPath('')}</h3>
```

You'll get the real path from which Websphere is serving the published files for the context that you are testing.

Comment: Yes, it works, but the value will vary in different servers. For my case, the published path is output path of the source code path.